# Should Python errors be documented in code or comments?

Tags: python, django, error-handling

Let's say we have a service method that performs its business logic by using one or more helper methods, where each helper method can raise one or more errors.

Because there can potentially be many helper methods that in total encapsulate lots of code, we want a way for folks using the service method to know all of the errors it can raise without needing to read through the implementation of every helper method.

To make this more concrete, let's assume this is being done in a Django context, where each view calls a service method, and then that view is then responsible for catching any errors the service method raises and returning an appropriate response for each to the user.

So question is, should the errors that each helper method can raise be documented by just re-raising the errors using a try/except, or should they be noted in a docstring?

For example, which is better here, service_method_v1 or service_method_v2?:

```
def service_method_v1():
    try:
        helper_method_1()
    except SomeError:
        raise


def service_method_v2():
    """
    Raises:
        SomeError, via helper_method_1()
    """

    helper_method_1()


helper_method_1():
    raise SomeError
```

I know there is some computational overhead when using try/except, but this purpose let's assume that this is negligible in terms of the end user experience.

Comment: If I saw the first function somewhere, I wouldn't think, "oh, that must be to document that this code can raise a SomeError". I would think that whoever wrote it had no idea how and when to handle exceptions.

Comment: The try-except fails to communicate what you were trying to communicate.

Comment: Interesting, I did an extensive search for python error handling best practices and didn't find anything that addressed this issue. How would you communicate what I'm trying to communicate, and why do you think the v1 implementation fails to communicate this?

Comment: This info goes in the docstring. Maybe it'll go in the annotations someday if Python 3.8 or whatever extends function annotations to describe exceptions. The v1 implementation fails to communicate your intent because `except` clauses are for *doing something* about exceptions.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any inherent reason why `except` clauses should be about doing something with exceptions, and not just documenting the list of errors that can be raised? I do like the Google docstring guidelines for having a `Raises:` section, but the idea of using this to document which specific helper functions can raise which errors seems awkward.

Comment: `except` clauses literally say *what to do* if a certain exception occurs. They do not say that the exception *can* occur, or that other exceptions can't. They are a control flow statement, not documentation. They are not introspectable and not visible anywhere unless you're actually reading the function's source code.

Comment: Using an `except` statement for this purpose is like installing a hidden metal detector in your door hooked up to nothing, no beeping or logs or anything, as an attempt to communicate the possibility that people entering the door might have metal.

Comment: I see your argument. At the same time, according to SICP, "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute." To me this implies that code that actually performs some sort of meaningful computation should be almost the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Hell no! That quote is saying that it's more important for humans to understand the code than for it to be fast. Utterly pointless code is hard to understand, because you waste a ton of time figuring out if it actually does something important and why anyone would write that code in the first place.

Comment: You don't write code just so people have something to read.